# How to set invisible the Label Group in Form Control?

Tags: forms, label, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have in a *Form* a *Group* it's possible to not show the it label?

In Group properties I have in DataGroup I have a Table Group.

It's possible to hide the Label, but keep the DataGroup reference?

For example, I want to set invisible this :

[image: my example_I want to set invisible this label]

Thanks all,

enjoy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for my question there is very easy solution, I wouuld like to share to community:

It's enough to set the *Form Control* property **FrameType** to **NONE** value, and not show the Label.

This is the pics:

[image]

[FrameType - Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/formgroupcontrol.frametype.aspx)

If you know another solution you can update the answer,

thanks all,

ad maiora!